# I am trying to create a crossword-puzzle solver in java

Tags: java, algorithm, puzzle, crossword

I was trying to figure out how to create a puzzle solver in java on my own but got stuck. I was able to read in the input from a file where the dimensions of the crossword are stored in an array. I'm having a problem searching for the word inside of the actual puzzle. This is what I have so far:

```
package crossWrdNMaze2;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class crossWord {



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("puzzle.txt"));
        //r and c describe the dimensions of the puzzle array
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        char[][] array = new char[r][c];
        //to scan puzzle chars into two-dimensional array
        for (int i = 0; i<r; i++){
            String getChar = new String(sc.next());
            for(int j=0; j<c; j++){
                array[i][j] = getChar.charAt(j);
            }//end for2
        }//end for1
        //Test to make sure array was filled
        for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<r;j++)
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
        System.out.println("");
        }//end for

        //scan in the number of words to be found in array (these integers follow the lines of 
        //letters which make up the array in the text file
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(num);

        for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
            //scan in the first word to be found
            String getWord = new String(sc.next());
            //determine word length to find size of array to look for in puzzle
            int z = getWord.length();
            char array2[] = new char[z];
            //scan new string (word we are looking for) into an array so we can look for one letter
            //at time in puzzle
            for(int j=0; j<z;j++){
                array2[j] = getWord.charAt(j);
            }//end for2
            //Size two array for the purpose of passing by reference so we can get coordinates of
            //word in puzzle
            int[] result = new int[1];
            //pass array(puzzle), array2(word we are looking for), result(coordinates of word in array),
            //r(number of rows in puzzle), c (number of columns in puzzle), z (length of word we
            //are searching for)
            findWord(array, array2, result, r, c, z);
            //print loaction of word each time through loop
            System.out.println(getWord + " is located at position (" + result[0] + ") (" + result[1] + ")");
        }//end for1

        sc.close();
    }//end main

static void findWord(char arr1[][], char arr2[], int[] result, int a, int b, int c){
        for(int i=0; i<a;i++){
            for(int j=0; i<b;j++){
                for(int k = 0; k<c;k++){
                    if(arr1[i][j] != arr2[k]){
                        System.out.println("Word not found!");//test to see if comparing letters and giving false return
                    }else if(arr1[i][j]== arr2[k]){
                    System.out.println("progress");//test to check if returning true when correct

                }//end if
            }//end for3
        }//end fosr2
    }//end for1
}//end function
}//end class
```

**EDIT:** I added some comments to the code, also I just remembered from an article I read recently
Happy Birthday Stack Overflow, I'm a long time reader but this is the first time I've ever posted.
Thanks again for your time

Comment: wooo... edit your post, this comment is unreadable!

Comment: You may want to copy your function from comments to the post.  Use `edit`.

Comment: Click [[edit]] option under your question and update it with your additional informations from comment. After that remove your comment.

Comment: Can you describe the algorithm you are going to use for solving the puzzle in pseudocode or plain English.

Comment: Is it the same `findWord()` method as in your post of a different version?

Comment: What do you mean by "solving" the puzzle? Do you have a list of words and need to locate them in the grid?  Your question is unclear.  "Solving" a crossword puzzle usually means interpreting the clues, which is far beyond anything much smaller than IBM's Watson.

Comment: Yep, and I think even Watson would have trouble with some of Merl Reagle's shenanigans...  :) :)

Comment: My apologies, The algorithm in english would be I want to search through the entire puzzle of letters for the first letter in the word i am searching for, then check the surrounding letters in a box around the first letter for the second letter in the string that I am searching for and so on until the word is found.

Comment: By solving the puzzle i mean that the program will eventually read the amount of words to look for followed by the actual list of words to look for from the input file. Then return the locations (coordinates of where it starts and ends) of the string in the original two-dimensional array (puzzle). The word can be found horizontally vertically or diagonally

Comment: the puzzle.txt file starts with two integers, seperated by a space, that describe the dimensions of the puzzle then continues with lines of characters, not seperated by spaces, that meet the dimensions previously mentioned.

Comment: Also is there a limit to the length of my post? After I made the edit it seems to be cut off.

Comment: Typo bug: `i<b` should be `j<b`.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can structure your problem is to extract a row, column, and eventually a diagonal strip of characters into a String (or character array) and perform your tests against that.

```
for (int row=0; row<rows; row++) {
    String strip=extractRow(row, arr);
    if (strip.contains(word)) { ... }
}
for (int col=0; col<cols; col++) {
    String strip=extractCol(col, arr);
    if (strip.contains(word)) { ... }
}
```

If you're just focused on extracting the sequences of characters that you want to compare your word against, it will make your problem more manageable.